# Error [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

It's indicated as [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.

I'm encountering a problem when it comes to error logging. The process functions well with try and else conditions, but it displays [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.

When attempting to submit the button for a second time, it still triggers the aforementioned issue.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lmTr.png)
and here is my code below!

```
import { ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, InteractionType, ChannelType, EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';
import languages from '../functions/loadLanguages.js';
import { getUserLanguage } from '../functions/userLanguageManager.js';
import config from '../../config.json' assert { type: 'json' };

const { TELE_REVIVE_LOG_ROOM } = config;
let requestStatus = null;

class SupportFormModal {
    create(type) {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('myFormModal')

        if (type === 'reviveTele') {
            modal.setTitle('Đơn Hỗ trợ Revive/Tele');
        } else {
            modal.setTitle('Đơn Hỗ trợ');
        }

        const idInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('idInput')
            .setLabel('Nhập ID của bạn')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const imageLinkInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('imageLinkInput')
            .setLabel('Link hình ảnh')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const reasonInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('reasonInput')
            .setLabel('Lí do')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);

        modal.addComponents(
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(idInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(imageLinkInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(reasonInput)
        );

        return modal;
    }

    async handleSubmit(interaction, client) {
        await interaction.deferReply();    
        if (!interaction.fields || !interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('imageLinkInput') || !interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('idInput') || !interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('reasonInput')) {
            return await interaction.followUp('Lỗi: Đã xảy ra sự cố khi lấy thông tin từ form. Vui lòng thử lại.');
        }       

        // Lấy thông tin từ modal
        const userId = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('idInput');
        const imageLink = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('imageLinkInput') || "Không có";
        const reason = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('reasonInput') || "Không có";

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`Đơn hỗ trợ của ${interaction.member.displayName} `)
            .setColor('#7aff00');

        embed.addFields(
            { name: 'Người chơi', value: userId },
            { name: 'Link ảnh', value: imageLink },
            { name: 'Lí do', value: reason },
        );

        if (imageLink.startsWith('http://') || imageLink.startsWith('https://')) {
            embed.setImage(imageLink);
        }

        embed.setTimestamp();

        const acceptButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('acceptRequest')
            .setLabel('Duyệt đơn')
            .setStyle('Success');

        const declineButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('declineRequest')
            .setLabel('Từ chối')
            .setStyle('Danger');

        const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(acceptButton, declineButton);

        const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(TELE_REVIVE_LOG_ROOM);
        if (logChannel && logChannel.type === ChannelType.GuildText) {
            logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow] });
        }

        // Phản hồi lại cho người dùng và đóng modal
        await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Cảm ơn bạn đã gửi thông tin! Vui lòng chờ 1 chút để ADMIN xét duyệt!!!', ephemeral: true });
    }
}

class DeclineReasonModal {
    create() {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('declineReasonModal')
            .setTitle('Nhập Lý Do Từ Chối');

        const reasonDeclineInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('reasonDeclineInput')
            .setLabel('Lí do từ chối')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);

        modal.addComponents(
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(reasonDeclineInput)
        );

        return modal;
    }

    async handleSubmit(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply();

        const declineReason = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('reasonDeclineInput');
        try {
            await interaction.user.send(`Đơn yêu cầu của bạn đã bị từ chối vì: ${declineReason}`);
        } catch (error) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: `Không thể gửi DM tới ${interaction.member.displayName}!` });
        }

        // Đóng modal
        await interaction.followUp({ content: `Lý do từ chối đã được gửi tới ${interaction.member.displayName}.`, components: [] });
    }
}

const modalInstances = {
    'myFormModal': new SupportFormModal(),
    'declineReasonModal': new DeclineReasonModal()
};

export default async (interaction, client) => {
    if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'Unknown command!', ephemeral: true });
        }

        const userLanguage = getUserLanguage(interaction.user.id) || 'en';

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction, userLanguage);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            const errorMessage = languages[userLanguage]?.errorExecutingCommand || 'Error executing command!';
            await interaction.reply({ content: errorMessage, ephemeral: true });
        }
    }

    if (interaction.isButton()) { 
        if (interaction.customId === 'openForm') {
            const modal = modalInstances['myFormModal'].create('reviveTele');
            try {
                await interaction.showModal(modal);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Không thể mở form. Vui lòng thử lại.' });
            }
        } else if (interaction.customId === 'acceptRequest') {
            await interaction.deferReply();
            if (requestStatus === 'declined') {
                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Đơn yêu cầu đã được từ chối trước đó!' });
            } else {
                requestStatus = 'accepted';
                try {
                    await interaction.user.send(`Đơn yêu cầu của bạn đã được duyệt`);
                    await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Đơn yêu cầu đã được duyệt!' });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    await interaction.followUp({ content: "Không thể gửi DM tới người dùng!" });
                }
            }
        } else if (interaction.customId === 'declineRequest') {
            if (requestStatus === 'accepted') {
                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Đơn yêu cầu đã được duyệt trước đó!' });
            } else {
                requestStatus = 'declined';
                const modal = modalInstances['declineReasonModal'].create();
                try {
                    await interaction.showModal(modal);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Không thể mở form từ chối. Vui lòng thử lại.' });
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    
    if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ModalSubmit) {   
        const modalInstance = modalInstances[interaction.customId];
        if (modalInstance) {
            return modalInstance.handleSubmit(interaction, client);
        } else {
            return await interaction.reply({ content: 'Unknown interaction.', ephemeral: true });
        } 
    }
};
```

Although, I even try using followUp() but it seems doesnt work, it keeps giving the same error and shuts the whole bot down.